# SELECTing additional column affects ORDER BY clause?

Tags: sql, select, sql-order-by

```
$query = "
SELECT a_orders.id, a_orders.billing, a_orders.type, 
    SUM(a_order_rows.quant_refunded*a_order_rows.price*((100-a_orders.discount)*.01)) as refund_total, 
    SUM(a_order_rows.quant*a_order_rows.price*((100-a_orders.discount)*.01)) as order_total,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT a_order_rows.date_refunded) as refund_dates
FROM a_order_rows JOIN a_orders 
ON a_order_rows.order_id = a_orders.id 
GROUP BY a_orders.id, a_orders.billing 
HAVING MAX(a_order_rows.quant_refunded) > 0 
ORDER BY a_order_rows.date_refunded DESC, a_orders.id DESC
LIMIT 50";

$query = "
SELECT a_orders.id, a_orders.billing, a_orders.type, 
    SUM(a_order_rows.quant_refunded*a_order_rows.price*((100-a_orders.discount)*.01))+a_orders.refund_adjustment as refund_total, 
    SUM(a_order_rows.quant*a_order_rows.price*((100-a_orders.discount)*.01)) as order_total,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT a_order_rows.date_refunded) as refund_dates
FROM a_order_rows JOIN a_orders 
ON a_order_rows.order_id = a_orders.id 
GROUP BY a_orders.id, a_orders.billing 
HAVING MAX(a_order_rows.quant_refunded) > 0 
ORDER BY a_order_rows.date_refunded DESC, a_orders.id DESC
LIMIT 50";
```

Notice `+a_orders.refund_adjustment` in line 2 of query 2? Just adding that is changing the order of results. Same thing happens if that column is selected without adding it into the aggregation (eg adding `a_orders.refund_adjustment,` after `a_orders.type,` on line 1).

After adding that column into the mix the results are no longer ordered as expected with `date_refunded DESC`. What gives? I cannot understand how this could affect result order in any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are ordering by `a_order_rows.date_refunded` after doing a `group by`.  The aggregation does *not* include this field.

What would be an error in any other database is accepted in MySQL.  However, it chooses an *arbitrary* value from one of the matching rows to place in this field.  This arbitrary value can change from one execution of the query to the next.  You can't depend on it.

If you want to order by `date_refunded` in a more stable way, then use an aggregation function:

```
ORDER BY min(a_order_rows.date_refunded) DESC, a_orders.id DESC
```

or

```
ORDER BY max(a_order_rows.date_refunded) DESC, a_orders.id DESC
```

Comment: Strange that it seemed to be working as planned without selecting the additional field, but that makes sense to me. Thank you!